Delphi FireDAC handle new detail records in CachedUpdateMode
I have in MariaDB normalized tables named
L1MasterTable  with columns

id
name
surname
email

L2AddressTable with columns

id
pid
City
Street
Country

L3AddressDetailTable with columns

id
pid
AddressDetail

Tables are in relation

L1MasterTable:L2AddressTable - 1:n
L2MasterTable:L2AddressTable - 1:n

In Delphi I have 3 very simple FDQueries that manage tables above
FDQuery1.Connection:=DataModule1.c; 
FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
FDQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT id, name, surname, email from L1MasterTable';
DataSource1.DataSet:=FDQuery1;
FDQuery1.FetchOptions.Mode := fmAll;
FDQuery1.CachedUpdates:=true; //I am working in CachedUpdatesMode for all tables
DataModule1.FDQueryOpen(FDQuery1,'FDQuery1 initDB');

FDQuery2.Connection:=DataModule1.c; //detail ISU a grid vpravo
FDQuery2.CachedUpdates:=true;
FDQuery2.SQL.Clear;
FDQuery2.SQL.Text:='SELECT id, pid, City, Street, Country from L2AddressTable order by pid'; 
FDQuery2.FetchOptions.Mode := fmAll;
FDQuery2.FetchOptions.DetailCascade:=true; //needed to be treated as Master/Detail mode
DataSource2.DataSet:=FDQuery2;
DataModule1.FDQueryOpen(FDQuery2,'FDQuery2 initDB');

FDQuery3.SQL.Clear;
FDQuery3.Connection:=DataModule1.c;
FDQuery3.CachedUpdates:=true;
FDQuery3.SQL.Text:='SELECT id, pid, addressdetail from L3AddressDetailTable order by pid'; 
DataSource3.DataSet:=FDQuery3;
FDQuery3.FetchOptions.DetailCascade:=true;
DataModule1.FDQueryOpen(FDQuery3,'FDQuery3 initDB');

My question is:
How do i handle cases when I create for example one record in L1MasterTable and also detailed records in L2MasterTable and L3MasterTable. In CachedUpdateMode has new record id <0. For example -1, -2, ...
When I want to add new record in L2MasterTable I do not know how to handle nonexisting id from parent table.
What is best practice how to handle this situation in Delphi using Firedac?
I must mention that my MariaDB works in MyISAM and i cant set relation directly in database.

All requested functionality is provided by FireDAC's component named TFDSchemaAdapter.
This component handles all id assignments.
Delphi documentantion: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDSchemaAdapter
Examples: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Athens/en/FireDAC.SchemaAdapterMemTable_Sample
Or examples on GitHub:
https://github.com/Embarcadero/RADStudio12Demos/tree/main/Object%20Pascal/Database/FireDAC/Samples/Comp%20Layer/TFDQuery/CachedUpdates/Centralized
Very simple snippet showing data saving do db, once everything is set according manual above:
 if FDSchemaAdapter1.UpdatesPending then
  begin
    FDSchemaAdapter1.ApplyUpdates; //applies correct IDs to all binded queries
    FDQuery1.CommitUpdates;
    FDQuery2.CommitUpdates;
    FDQuery3.CommitUpdates;
  end;

